# Unable to reload data to a DataTable with additional information from a new nurl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using the [DataTable plugin](https://datatables.net).

I am loading the DataTable. Then I am attempting to reload the table, while preserving the existing content, with additional information acquired from another json file. However, there is no reload occurring.

```
var resourcetable = $('#table').DataTable({
"ajax": {
    "url": "QueryDataService.asmx/GetData1",
    "dataSrc": ""
},
"columns": [
    { "data": "Column1" },
    { "data": "Column2" },
    { "data": "Column3" }                ]
});

resourcetable.ajax.url("QueryDataService.asmx/GetData2").reload();
```

The error I see is: Uncaught TypeError: resourceusagetable.ajax.url(...).reload is not a function

Appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reload()` is callable from `ajax`, not `url()`. `load()` is callable from `url()`, so i would try `resourcetable.ajax.url("QueryDataService.asmx/GetData2").load();`

Comment: When I use the load function as you suggested the existing data gets overwritten. How can I ensure the new data merges with the existing data when I call "resourcetable.ajax.url("QueryDataService.asmx/GetData2").load();" ? Thanks!

Comment: I would keep a reference to the old data, load the new data, then re-add the old data. `var data = resourcetable.data(); resourcetable.ajax.url("QueryDataService.asmx/GetData2").load();` resourcetable.rows.add(data).draw()`. This is just off the top of my head, there could be a more standard way.

Comment: That's clever. Strangely, its not working. 'data' [var data = resourcetable.data()] does not seem to get populated. Thanks!